# Conditionally creating formatted string from elements and attributes in XQuery

Tags: xquery

I'm trying to convert an xml document into a specific tab separated flat file structure. Most of the elements can be mapped to single columns or concatenated simply using fn:string-join(), but I have some elements where the mapping is more complicated. An example element looks like this:

```
<record>
  <details>
    <passports>
      <passport country="">0018061/104</passport>
      <passport country="UK">0354761445</passport>
      <passport country="USA">M001806145</passport>
    </passports>
  </details>
<record>
```

and I need to create a column that looks like this:

```
  0018061/104;(UK) 0354761445;(USA) M001806145
```

so if the `@country` attribute is not `""` it is put in `()`, otherwise it is omitted. The element value follows and each element is separated by `;`.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
for $record in //record
  return concat($record/@uid/string(),
  (: ... other columns ... :)
  "&#09;", <S>{for $r in //$record/details/passports/passport
    return concat("(", $r/@country, ") ", $r, ";")}</S>/string()
  ,"&#10;")
```

I'm sure there's an easier way, but this almost does the job - it produces:

```
  () 0018061/104;(UK) 0354761445;(USA) M001806145
```

Ideally I'd like to know the correct way to do this, otherwise just removing the empty brackets where `@country=""` would suffice.

Comment: Please generally provide example input that _fits_ the query you're posting (here, the wrapping record and details tags are missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `if` clause right in the outer `concat` (I added some newlines for better readability in the answer, you can of course remove them as you wish):

```
concat(
  if ($r/@country != "")
  then concat("(", $r/@country, ") ")
  else "",
  $r,
  ";"
)
```

New result of the query:

```
0018061/104; (UK) 0354761445; (USA) M001806145;
```

You could also go for an implicit loop

```
/record/details/passports/passport/string-join(
  (
    "&#09;",
    if (@country != "")
    then "(" || @country || ") "
    else (),
    .
  ), ""
)
```

or explicitly loop over the results and still have a cleaner query (by replacing the concatenation operator `||` by respective `concat(...)` calls, you would stay XQuery 1.0 compatible):

```
for $record in /record/details/passports/passport
return (
  "&#09;" || (
    if ($record/@country != "")
    then "(" || $record/@country || ") "
    else ()
  ) || $record
)
```

Both cases use the implicit newlines inserted by BaseX in-between tokens, alternatively you can of course add them as you had before.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried an if statement but I must have done something wrong with the syntax. This works great, thanks. Btw - is there a better way that avoids the use of the loop or adding the surrounding <>'s?

Comment: What query processor are you using, does it support XQuery 3.0?

Comment: BaseX 8.2 - I believe it does

Comment: BaseX supports XQuery 3, yes. I added some proposals how you also could get the results for inspiration. The reason you needed the `<S>` element is that the `for` loop returns a sequence of strings, not a single one; you could have used `string-join($seq, "")` instead (while replacing `$seq` with the loop you already have).

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll work on your samples above. Can't quite get them working in my example, but it's a useful start point.

Comment: Note that the answer seems to suggest that the "implicit loop" is an XQuery 3.0 feature, which is not.

Comment: Indeed, mixed that up with XPath 1/XPath 2. Thank you for pointing this out!